# JavaScript loop with output: 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I saw an output of a loop that make the result: 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

I know the above loop is wrong and unusual and maybe you ask what's the usage of this loop, but i want to know how can i implement that.

Thanks

Comment: If the elements of the list/array are integers, then it's out of order. If they are strings, then it's correct.

Comment: Are you asking for the JS code to design a loop to print those numbers?

Comment: What loop? All you have shown is some numbers and no code. This isn't a code writing or homework service. Please read through [ask]

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yeah JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use numbers and sort it as strings with build in [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback. This method uses sorting by string.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

array.sort();
console.log(array);
```

Or you could build a tree and read it with depth first alogrithm with priority of `number` property.

```js
var i,
    tree = {};

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    i.toString().split('').reduce(function (r, c, i, cc) {
        r[c] = r[c] || {};
        if (i + 1 === cc.length) {
            r[c].number = true;
        }
        return r[c];
    }, tree);
}

Object.keys(tree).forEach(function iter(object, value) {
    object.number && console.log(value);
    return function(k) {
        k === 'number' || Object.keys(object[k]).forEach(iter(object[k], value + k));
    };
}(tree, ''));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, might be another way?

Comment: @MasoudGhorbani, please see edit.